# format of the x-axis from 1 e+06 to 1 Mio

Tags: r, plot

i want to change the format of the x-axis of a plot in R from 1 e+06 to 1 Mio.

What is the right comand to do that?

Thank you for your help.

Jonas

Comment: what kind of plot? Base R, lattice, ggplot2?  Could you give us a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you work with a base R scatter plot and further assuming you mean what you say, namely that you want labels like "1 Mio" (instead of the number 1000000) on the x-axis, this could work for you:

**DATA**:

```
x <- seq(1000000, 10000000, 1000000)
y <- 1:10
```

**SOLUTION**:

```
plot(x,y, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = x, labels = paste(1:10, "Mio", sep = " "), las = 2)
```

This solution avoids printing the default x-axis labels by setting `xaxt = "n"`and by defining a customized x-axis including the desired axis labels